# Excluding subdomains from being crawled by search engines

Tags: .htaccess, iis, robots.txt

I have:

```
domain.com
Customer1.domain.com
Customer2.domain.com
...
CustomerN.domain.com
```

I want domain.com to be crawled and indexed by search engines, but not Customer1.domain.com, Customer2.domain.com, ... CustomerN.domain.com

Subdomains are create dynamically, one per a customer, and I want they to not display anyhow in search results. 
I did try to solve this by robots.txt file, but it doesn't help me.

My application is hosted on IIS server.
Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Robots.txt for multiple domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373376/robots-txt-for-multiple-domains)

Comment: "I did try to solve this by robots.txt file, but it doesn't help me.": Why not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one robots.txt for each subdomain. They must contain the following statements (from https://youtu.be/G29Zt-UH_Ko):

```
user-agent: *
disallow: /
```